# What happens to code after await if the Xamarin.Forms Page is popped from navigation?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

Let's say I have a `MyContentPage` that's pushed onto the navigation stack from somewhere as follows:

```
navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage());
```

And inside `MyContentPage` somewhere, there's:

```
await SomeLongRunningTask();
// Code after the await
```

What happens to `Code after the await` if Back is pressed by the user while `SomeLongRUnningTask` is still executing, and as a result `MyContentPage` is popped from the navigation stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is nothing, your task is still running and your viewmodal and likely your page will be hanging around in memory

If you would like to end that task, then you will need to make use of a cancellation token or some sort of way of stopping the processing.

**Update**

> what happens to code after the await. Will // Code after the await run
>   even though the page has been popped?

It will run

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I'm not concerned about what happens to the Task though, the question is about what happens to code _after_ the await. Will `// Code after the await` run even though the page has been popped?

Comment: Are you `await`ing the `PushAsync`?

Comment: As a further answer, why are you asking?  Why not just try it and see?

Comment: @Neil No the `PushAsync` isn't being awaited. How does that make a difference? To answer your other question, if I could I would :) But due to a lot of backend requirements, and no easy way to mock services to get to this point of the application where the shit's hitting the fan, I can't.

Comment: @Saruman Thank you. So if the code following `await` does a `Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`, I'm guessing unexpected bad things will happen?

Comment: @AjLearning basically yes. you will have popped everything off the stack, potentially while your in another page. However you could check if the page is active or whether it exists on the stack and act accordingly